# The await operator can only be used in a method or lambda marked with the 'async' modifier

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I'm getting this error (in Title), here's my code

```
public async Task<int> ReadTextFile()
    {
        //
        // Read in a file line-by-line, and store it all in a List.
        //
        var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("Users.txt"))
        {
            String line;
            while ((line = await reader.ReadLineAsync()) != null)
            {
                String[] splitLines = line.Split(' ');
                User user;
                if (splitLines.Length == 3)
                {
                    user = new User
                        {
                            FirstName = splitLines[0],
                            MiddleName = splitLines[1],
                            LastName = splitLines[2]
                        };
                }

                else if (splitLines.Length == 2)
                {
                    user = new User
                    {
                        FirstName = splitLines[0],
                        LastName = splitLines[1]
                    };
                }

                else
                {
                    user = new User
                    {
                        FirstName = splitLines[0]
                    };
                }

                users.Add(user);
            }
        }
        int number = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 6000; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < 1000; k++)
                {
                    number += 1;
                } 
            }
        }
            watch.Stop();
        var elapsedMs = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        return number;
    }


public async Task<List<User>> GetUsers()
    {
        await this.ReadTextFile();
        return this.users;
    }


 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MainWindowViewModel viewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();
        var x = await viewModel.GetUsers();//ERROR IS ON THIS LINE
        //dataGrid.ItemsSource = await viewModel.GetUsers();


    }
}
```

Going by the example here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh524395.aspx
My code should work, so I'm not sure what's happening, can someone please help?

Comment: `var x = await viewModel.GetUsers();` is not allowed outside of a method, and the fact that you didn't pick up on that is a very strong hint that you're not showing enough real code in your question to make it properly answerable.

Comment: Can you add the ReadTextFile method to your post - is that marked as async ?

Comment: hi auburg I've added the full code, see above

Answer (score 1):

The `var x = await viewModel.GetUsers();` must also be on an `async` method. You can't `await` in a method that is not marked as `async`.

**Update**: After your update with more code, you are trying to `await` a method in your `Button_Click` method.

For your specific case, you need to mark your `Button_Click` as `async`. Note that `async void` is not recommended (it's always better to return a `Task`), but this is the *specific case* why `async void` is supported: to allow delegate with a specific `void` signature (which you can't change) to be marked as `async`. So just:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // ...
    var x = await viewModel.GetUsers();
    // ...
}
```

When you `await` on something (on an *awaitable*), the important part is that the method **where you await** is marked `async`. That's **exactly** what the compiler error is telling you: read it carefully:

> The await operator can only be used in a method or lambda marked with the 'async' modifier

It **doesn't** say (which seems it's what you understood):

> The await operator can only be used when calling a method marked with the 'async' modifier

Generally, you'll await on a `Task` (or `Task<T>`): that's what you are doing there. The fact that `GetUsers` is marked `async` or not, is irrelevant: the important part is that it returns an *awaitable* (again, typically a `Task`: in your case a `Task<List<User>>`).

Whether that method (`GetUsers`) needs to be marked `async` or not depends only on whether that method itself uses `await` (in your case, it does), not on whether *the caller method* will await on its result or not.

If the MSDN is not clear to you, at the very least, I recommend that you **carefully** read and understand the *official* [Async/Await FAQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/12/10293335.aspx) (it's not really *official* but it comes from Microsoft and I found it easier to understand than the MSDN, which I reckon might be a bit dense sometimes-).

Comment: The method **where you are awaiting** must be async. Not *necessarily* the method you are calling.

Comment: @Jcl significantly, the method you are awaiting must return an awaitable type, traditionally a `Task`.

Comment: @Gusdor yeah, was just writing that specific edit when your comment popped up :-)